# Input method for timer app

Tags: android, android-input-method

I'm new to Android and currently working on a timer app to get familiar with it.

I'd like to get a user input for setting the timer. I'd like to have it in an HH:mm:ss format. The UI shall initially display the "00h 00m 00s" string and a number keyboard, and as the user types numbers, the field should get filled up from the right to the left, overflowing between second/minutes/hours.
Example:
User types "123" > 00:01:23

My current idea is to have 3 TextViews for the numbers and 3 TextViews for the h/m/s markers, then also add 10 Buttons with numbers on it to fill the fields up. But I guess there must be an easier way to do this.
My question is: would it possible to make this happen with soft input method and EditTexts? I'd also interested in other ways to implement this, as long the format constraint (00h 00m 00s) is respected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:inputType="Number" to display the number keyboard.Use TextWatcher to display your result.For example:

```
EditText tv_filter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter);
TextWatcher fieldValidatorTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (filterLongEnough()) {
            populateList();
        }
    }

    private boolean filterLongEnough() {
        return tv_filter.getText().toString().trim().length() > 2;
    }
};
tv_filter.addTextChangedListener(fieldValidatorTextWatcher);
```

And then, in the end, display your result in texView using your logic of splitting the input string accordingly.I know its very generic but your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. :)

Are you saying that I'd need _one_ EditText field with android:inputType="Number" for getting the input and _one_ TextView to display it? I'm fairly new to this and I have difficulties overseeing what your code snippet does. :) What is this snippet intended to do? I see that we add a TextChangedListener to the tv_filter EditText, but what is this doing?

Comment: This snippet will add a textWatcher to your edit text field where the user is going to enter the numbers and then you can implement your logic here of splitting the inputs and then setting the desired results in textView.For example: Here I am using my method filterLongEnough to do something and populating a list.But you can change that.'code'
    String[] strarr=(s.toString()).split("\\s");
    strarr[0].concat(":");
    strarr[1].concat(":");
    strarr[2].concat(":");
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(strarr[0]+strarr[1]+strarr[2]);

Comment: I see, so essentially is need to implement populatelist. This makes now perfect sense. But wouldn't be the text that I type into the EditText displayed as well? Or the idea is to actually have an EditText in the UI but hide it?

Comment: Yes!But then after you return from populatelist() you can again clear your editText.Let me know if you are able to do it